# Android Service - stopSelf() not doing what it's supposed to

Tags: android, android-service

I have an unbound service running in the background for my application.
I want to the service to be able to stop itself if some conditions are met. I tried calling

```
stopSelf();
```

but this doesn't work. The service is still running and using up memory. The weirdest part is that it it goes through

```
onDestroy()
```

after calling StopService()... This is what makes me confused. Why is it still there if it went through onDestory()?

Comment: How did you determine that ~"**the service is still running**"?  Did you create this service in a separate process or something?